# find wave discontinuity by using fourier transform( wav file's tick noise)

Tags: python, python-3.x, fft, wave

```
    audio_sample, sampling_rate = librosa.load('a.wav', sr=None)

    S = np.abs(librosa.stft(audio_sample, n_fft=1024, hop_length=512, win_length=1024, window=signal.hann))
    
    mag_db = librosa.amplitude_to_db(S)
    mag_n = _normalize(mag_db)
    librosa.display.specshow(mag_n, y_axis='linear', x_axis='time', sr=sampling_rate)
```

I did some **stft** and then **spechow**. but I want to find the point(time) where wave discontinuity.

example) I want to know discontinuity point of the wave file

I mean like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use **derivatives** to find discontinuities in a wave. To take the derivative of the wave we can use **convolution** with a filter.
Here's a sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generating the wave
angle1 = np.linspace(0, 5*np.pi/2, 100)
wave1  = np.sin(angle1)
angle2 = np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi/2)
wave2  = np.sin(angle2)
angle3 = np.linspace(np.pi/2, 2*np.pi)
wave3  = np.sin(angle3)
wave   = np.append(wave1, wave2)
wave   = np.append(wave, wave3)

# differentiation
filter = [-1, 1]
dif    = np.convolve(wave, filter)
absdif = np.abs(dif)
print('discontinuity at:', np.where(absdif > 0.75)[0])

plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
plt.plot(wave, label='input wave')
plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
plt.plot(dif, label='dirivative')
plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
plt.plot(absdif, label='absolut of derivative')

plt.show()
```

Output graph:
[image]

Comment: can you give me some more guide?
i tried but i got these error

Comment: dif    = np.convolve('a.wav', filter)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in convolve
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 817, in convolve
    return multiarray.correlate(a, v[::-1], mode)
ValueError: data type must provide an itemsize

Comment: You r directly passing file to convolve so it is giving error. First read the .wav file then convert into numpy array and then take derivative using convolve function